# Custom Post Type Dashboard Tab not displaying any posts

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, init

I created a custom post:

```
/*= Add Custom Post Type: Board Members
/****************************************************/ 
add_action( 'init', 'create_board_posttype' );
function create_board_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'board',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Board Members' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Board Member' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Board Member' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Board Member' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Board Member' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Board Member' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Board Members' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'No Board Members Found' ),
        'archives' => __( 'Board Members Archives' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into Board Member' ),
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'board'),
    )
  );
}
```

I then went and added 10 posts successfully and they are displaying on the frontend fine.

Fast forward 4 weeks and I went in to edit a post but I am seeing "No board members found".

It shows that there are 10 Board Members published by actually displays none in the list:

```
All (10) | Published (10)

No Board Members Found
```

Clearly WP knows there are board members (All (10)) but it wont show them... I don't know where to start?

Ok, I found the issue but I don't understand why.

I have another custom_post_type: `jobs`

On the frontend I try to filter jobs within last x days.  When I remove this code, the Board Members re-appear:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_query_vars' );
function custom_query_vars( $query ) {
    
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) 
    {
        if ( is_archive('job') ) 
        {
            $days = get_field('job_expiry_days', 'option');
            $query->set( 'date_query', array(
                                'column'  => 'post_date',
                                'after'   => '- '.$days.' days'
            ) );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pre_get_posts` doesn't just run on the frontend, it runs on *all* post queries, and that includes RSS feeds, XMLRPC, AJAX, REST API, ***and WP Admin.***

You need to check in your `pre_get_posts` filter and exit early so that it only applies to the places you want it to apply to.

e.g.

```php
if ( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}
```

Additionally, this code is incorrect:

```php
if ( is_archive('job') )
```

This checks if the main query is a job archive, but it should be checking if `$query` is a job archive, so it needs to be `$query->is_archive( 'job' )`.

This is also followed by another bug:

```php
$days = get_field('job_expiry_days', 'option');
```

If `job_expiry_days` is not set, then it will be a falsey value, resolving to `0`, meaning only posts older than 0 days ago will be found, aka nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer the question, but note that [`is_archive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_archive/) **does *not* accept any parameters**. If you want to check if the query is for an archive of a custom post type, use [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive), e.g. `is_post_type_archive( 'job' )` if the post type is `job`.

And for example, if the CPT archive was at `example.com/jobs`, then `if ( is_post_type_archive( 'job' ) )` would return true only when viewing that `/jobs` page.